# Cpanel - subdomain outside public_html

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, out, public-html

I had two domains on one hosting account, managed by cpanel. During the second domain installation I opted to use root folder outside public_html because the second site was going to have independent ftp administration not related to the one of the first domain at all. So I didn't want the files of the second site to be accessible in public_html. 
That worked pretty well until the second domain expired and wasn't going to be renewed. However, despite website isn't public already, I want to have web access on it for testing and other purposes but it seems like cpanel doesn't allow subdomain directories outside public_html. 
Is there a way, to achieve that without having to migrate all subdomain files to public_html and thus - making them accessible for the administrators on the main domain (which is undesired)?

Comment: It is Bulgarian hosting provider "Superhosting".

Comment: It depends on your host if this is allowed, but here's how to do it if it is possible: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/modify-addon-domain-document-root

Comment: Isn't that for independent (bought) domain names? If so, it works for them. But I need to make a subdomain (example: subdomain.maindomain.whatever) extending the only remaining domain assigned to the account.  

Edit: Your example points public_html as main folder too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by having two cPanel hosting accounts:

```
- domain.com
- subdomain.domain.com
```

In case the hosting accounts are in different servers, you should make an `A record` `subdomain.domain.com` pointing to the server that specific hosting account is created.

By doing that, you will have two separated environments, usernames, passwords and databases will be different from each other. The hosting account domain.com won't be able to see the files and manage anything on subdomain.domain.com. The same applies vice-versa.

Comment: That means purchasing another hosting plan (I am tired of free web hosting restrictions and inconveniences). The better (cheaper) way would be buying another domain name.

Answer (score -1):

create folder out side www as for example `hello`. and in `cpanel/subdomains` point that such as `../hello` in Document Root